# Defining my_times Enumerator based on my_each Enumerator?

Tags: ruby

Say that I have my own implementation of `each`:

```
class Array
  def my_each
    c = 0
    until c == size
      yield(self[c])
      c += 1
    end
    self
  end
end
```

How would I do my own implementation of `times` by using my_each? Here is my approach:

```
class Integer
  def my_times
    Array.new(self) { |i| i }.my_each do |el|
      yield el
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't particularly like it because I am creating an Array. But, is there any other way I could accomplish this?

Comment: If `my_each` is (supposed to be) working exactly as `each`, then there should be no difference whether you define `my_times` based on `my_each` or on `each`. Your mentioning of `my_each` is redundant. You should just ask how to implement `my_times` based on `each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
class Integer
  def my_times
    return (0...self).to_enum unless block_given?
    (0...self).each { |i| yield i }
  end
end

5.my_times { |i| puts i*i }
0
1
4
9
16

5.my_times #=> #<Enumerator: 0...5:each>
```

I have used [Range#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-each). To use `Array#my_each` we'd have to convert the range to an array:

```
[*(0...self)].my_each { |i| yield i }
```

Recall that [Integer#times](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Integer.html#method-i-times) returns an enumerator if no block is given.  The same is true of [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-each); you need to fix `my_each` for it to be equivalent to `Array#each`.

You don't need `each` or `my_each`, however:

```
class Integer
  def my_times
    return (0...self).to_enum unless block_given?
    i = 0
    while(i < self) do
      yield i
      i += 1
    end
  end
end

5.my_times { |i| puts i*i }
0
1
4
9
16

5.my_times #=> #<Enumerator: 0...5:each>
```